# How do I perform a command substitution in tclsh?

Tags: tcl, tclsh

I want to capture the stdout of a command in a variable, similarly to command substitution in Bash:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
x="$(date)"
echo $x
```

I tried doing the same in tclsh but it doesn't do what I want:

```sh
#!/bin/tclsh
set x [date]
echo $x
```

If I execute the script with`tclsh myscript.tclsh` it gives an error:

```
invalid command name "date"
    while executing
"date "
    invoked from within
"set x [ date ]"
```

On the other hand, if I open a TCL interactive shell with `tclsh`, it does not give an error and the  `echo` line prints an empty string.

Why is my program giving different results when I execute the script with or without the REPL? And it there a way to capture the output of a shell command and store it in a variable, similarly to command substitution in Bash?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When not using Tcl interactively, you need to *explicitly* use the `exec` command to run a subprocess.

```
set x [exec date]
# Tcl uses puts instead of echo
puts $x
```

In interactive use, the unknown command handler guesses that that's what you wanted. In some cases. Be explicit in your scripts, please!

---

You should probably replace running a `date` subprocess with the appropriate calls to the built-in `clock` command:

```
# Get the timestamp in seconds-from-the-epoch
set now [clock seconds]
# Convert it to human-readable form
set x [clock format $now -format "%a %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S %Z"]
```

(That almost exactly matches the output of `date` on this system. The spacing isn't quite the same, but that doesn't matter for a lot of uses.)

Comment: The interactive uses stuff is government by a magic global. I'm not going to write what it is here because _you're not supposed to use it in scripts at all._ Magical shortcuts are all very well for interactive use, but they tend to hurt far more than they help when making a reliable program…

Comment: Thanks! I was only using `date` to keep the question succinct but the suggestion of `clock` is also useful to know.